# Questions on implementing enterprise (paid-for) features in the free version

Tags: discussion, questions

I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220606/ag-grid-expanding-collapsing-tree-data) on Stack Overflow. It explains that it wants to implement a feature of [ag-Grid Enterprise](https://www.ag-grid.com/license-pricing.php) ([row grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/index.php)) but that they don't want to pay for the Enterprise edition. I personally have created a work around that simulates this row grouping feature using just the features of the free version.

Should the best answer to this question be "the author of this software put in some hard work, support him for his efforts," or is it ok to give some example code on how one can side step and simulate the enterprise features without paying for it?

Comment: if your code uses the public api and doesn't violate the legal terms I see no problem providing an answer that shows a work around

Comment: As an additional incentive, you could list the drawbacks (if there are any) of your workaround and mention the full paid-for method won't suffer from these.

Comment: @rene Even if it *does* violate the terms of the product, it's not SO's responsibility to enforce it.

Comment: @Servy that is true. I wasn't worried about SO's liability but more about that of the OP's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The author of this software put in some hard work, support him for his efforts

This is not an answer. On top of that, it's not Stack Overflow's responsibility to enforce the terms of service for other products.

---

Posting an answer with a work around, provided you explain the answer and provide necessary code, *is* an answer. There are plenty of "workarounds" posted on Stack Overflow. There are times those are the only viable answer when restrictions like "I don't want to pay for the Enterprise version" are placed in the question.

With such answers, it's not out of line to explain the downsides of the work around versus using the official method (in this case, paying for the upgrade).

Answer (score -6):

As the author of ag-Grid, should I be posting on stack overflow how to implement yourselves the enterprise features??? Personally I think not, and if others did, then it turns stackoverflow into a form of pirate bay. Please support software development :)

Comment: You're certainly not *obligated* to help people use your software in ways that you don't want them to, but, likewise, SO isn't responsible for prohibiting people from using your software in ways that you don't want them to; that's *your* responsibility as a developer.  Additionally, someone creating their own free product and sharing it with others is not pirating, even if you also are providing a product that performs the same actions for some cost.  It's only pirating if they're asking how to, say, trick your software into thinking that they're a paying customer when they are not.